# json.decode doesnt convert Map<String, Map<String,dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have json like this called resultMap

```
{
  "someInfo":{
    "moreInfo":"test",
    "moreInfo2":"test2"
  }
}
```

from this I need to convert `Map<String,Map<String,dynamic>>` but `json.decode(json['resultMap'])` doesn't work on Map inside Map

How can i convert this?

Comment: You should use `Map<string, dynamic>` instead of `Map<String,Map<String,dynamic>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON parser does not attempt to guess at the type of map elements. All JSON objects are parsed into maps of type `Map<String,dynamic>`. That allows you to *add* any value to the map and convert it back to JSON. The fact that your map only contains other maps as values might just be a happy coincidence, and make the type of the outer map `Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>` would break code which expects to read data like this and then add other kinds of values to the outer map, like strings.

So, the type is `Map<String, dynamic>` If you *know* that it contains only maps, and you don't plan to change that, then you can do:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(...);
var mapmap = map.cast<String, Map<String, dynamic>>();
print(mapmap["key"]["otherKey"]);
```

This wraps the original map so that the values are cast to `Map<String, dynamic>` when you look them up, so you don't have to do it yourself.

If you then put something non-map into the original map, like `map["gotcha"] = "string";`, then `mapmap["gotcha"]` will throw a type error when you try to read it. So don't do that.